# join() blocks continuation of main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to be able to start a new thread from the main thread in my program. At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
std::thread acceptThread(Accept);
acceptThread.join();
```

But that blocks the continuation of the main thread until the `acceptThread` is "done". I don't want this. I just want it to run on a different thread so the main thread can continue. How do I do this?

What I want is a loop that accepts incoming connections and a loop that sends/receives data. These should be running at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of `join()` is to block until the other thread exits. Just get rid of it. Why'd you add it in the first place?

Comment: I didn't know it did that after I tried it. Ok got it! Thanks

Comment: @Dries: What is it that you want to do? Just creating the `std::thread` object is enough to create the thread.

Comment: Just trying to create a seperate thread to run a while loop on that should not interfere with the rest of the application. I'm working on my program to be able to accept multiple connections (starting from the msdn client/server winsock code)

Comment: @Dries: You've already done that by creating the `std::thread`. You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

> std::thread acceptThread(Accept);

creates and start a new thread that will call the "Accept" method, which is enough in your case.

Your second line is not needed, join would block the current thread unil the joined one exits.

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join